# Error accessing/loading External Table - due to characterset?

Tags: oracle

Oracle 12cR2 - I am needing to move data from one database to another.
Due to reasons I won't go into, the data is dumped as a CSV file from one system, and I load it into another system as CSV files with External table definitions.  The issue I am running into has to do with the fact that some data has 'e' with the accent markers over it  (é).

Both databases are defined as AL32UTF8.  Both source and destination tables are identical in structure.  When I export the data into a CSV file, I get é in several of the rows.  When I try to import via external tables, I get the following error:

```
KUP-04021: field formatting error for field <field name>
KUP-04037: terminator not found
KUP-04101: record 7476 rejected in file <CSV File Name>
```

If I open the CSV file in Notepad++ and change 'e with accent' (é) to a standard 'e', the import works fine. In spot checking, each row that errored out has é.

I am confused as to why I am getting this error.  I will need to move the data on a regular basis. I do not want to have to do through a manual data cleanup every time.  I would have thought that that same Characterset would have prevented this error.

How do I resolve this issue? My External Table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE  "table_x" 
   (    
    "FROM_REF" VARCHAR2(30),        
    "FY" VARCHAR2(30), 
    ...
    "SUPPORT" NUMBER
   )
    organization external (
  type oracle_loader
  default directory ext_data_files      
  access parameters 
  (
  records delimited BY 0x'0A'
  CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8  
  skip 1
  BADFILE 'bad_%a_%p.bad' 
  LOGFILE 'log_%a_%p.log'   
  fields terminated by ','
  optionally enclosed BY '"'  
  missing field VALUES are NULL 
  REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS  
)
  location ('WS_FY18.csv')
)
reject limit 0;
```

Comment: Did you define `CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8` (part of `ACCESS PARAMETERS`) in your external table?

Comment: @lad2025 - I had not.  I have added it, but it does not change the error.  Still bombs out on the same line.  I have added my definition to the original question.

Comment: I would try to add also `STRING SIZES ARE IN CHARACTERS ` below characterset

Comment: Tried... no difference

Comment: Are you sure the text file is saved as correct UTF8?  Perhaps the "é" is being saved as extended ASCII instead of true Unicode but Notepad++ displays it the same either way.  Try using a character that's not part of extended ASCII in the export, and see if it shows up correctly.  Or check the hex of the file and verify the character set.

Comment: @John,  Please submit this as answer, and I will accept.  When I changed the Characterset to 'CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1'  I am able to load the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the text file is saved as correct UTF8?

Perhaps the "é" is being saved as extended ASCII instead of true Unicode but Notepad++ displays it the same either way.  Try using a character that's not part of extended ASCII in the export, and see if it shows up correctly.  Or check the hex of the file and verify the character set.

Comment: When I changed the Characterset to 'CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1' I am able to load the data.